# Match complete word at start, middle and end of string

Tags: python, regex

How to replace the complete word `abc.def` at start, middle and end of string but do not replace the text like `abc.def.au` or `d.abc.def`:

```
line = "abc.def abc.def.au abc.def d.abc.def abc.def"
new_line = re.sub("abc.def", "-----", line)
print(line)
print(new_line)
```

Current output:

```
abc.def abc.def.au abc.def d.abc.def abc.def
----- -----.au ----- d.----- -----
```

Expected output:

```
abc.def abc.def.au abc.def d.abc.def abc.def
----- abc.def.au ----- d.abc.def -----
```

Can this be done in one `re.sub()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use line anchors. `^` and `$` matches only a the start of the string and end of the string respectively, so you could use them like such:

```
line = "abc.def abc.def.au abc.def d.abc.def abc.def"
new_line = re.sub(r"^abc\.def|abc\.def$", "-----", line)
print(line)
print(new_line)
```

Note that it is safer to raw regex strings, and escape the `.` character (which matches almost *any* character in regex).

---

If you want to replace only *whole* words you will need some lookarounds instead:

```
line = "abc.def abc.def.au abc.def d.abc.def abc.def"
new_line = re.sub(r"(?<!\S)abc\.def(?!\S)", "-----", line)
print(line)
print(new_line)
```

[ideone demo](http://ideone.com/3xOJDe)

`(?<!\S)` will prevent a match if `abc.def` is preceded by a non-space character.

`(?!\S)` will prevent a match if `abc.def` is followed by a non-space character.

Comment: He also wants to replace the complete word in the middle of a string

Comment: @RainLee I'm not sure how I missed 'middle' but *string* usually is the whole line/text. I saw 'middle' in the question later and have added it in.